# Aggregate function not allowed in Set statment in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to update one table with values from another table (msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory). Since I need to get the max values of the run_time and run_date, I kept getting 'aggregate function not allowed in set statement' error. As a workaround, I tried the following but something isn't right because ALL the values in every row are the same, indicating either an error in the join or something I can't figure out.This is what I have (which is not correct):

```
UPDATE inventory.dbo.books SET 
   auth_time = t1.at,
   auth_date = t1.ad
FROM (SELECT MAX(run_time) AS at, MAX(run_date) AS ad
      FROM  msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h 
       INNER JOIN inventory.dbo.books t 
          ON h.job_id = t.jobid) t1
```

ALSO, I need to be able to convert the run_time into decimal(10,2) format (as the auth_time field is that) and run_date into datetime (as auth_time is datetime format).

Comment: How did you get on with the two answers below, Damon?

Answer (score 1):

You're so close!

Just move your subquery reference from the From Clause to a subquery in the Set for each field.

Try this:

```
UPDATE inventory.dbo.books SET 
   auth_time = (SELECT MAX(run_time) 
                FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h 
                    INNER JOIN inventory.dbo.books t 
                        ON h.job_id = t.jobid)
   , auth_date = (SELECT MAX(run_date) 
                    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h 
                        INNER JOIN inventory.dbo.books t 
                            ON h.job_id = t.jobid);
```

The subquery in the SET for each field essentially returns a single value when the subquery is executed. Therefore, the use of a subquery doesn't break any of the rules of the set operation.

If your logic starts getting too complicated and your set fields too numerous to want to repeat everything as a subquery for each field, then you can also use a CTE.

```
With CTE as (
Select MAX(run_time) as at
    , MAX(run_date) as ad 

FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h 
    INNER JOIN inventory.dbo.books t 
        ON h.job_id = t.jobid
) 

Update #Temp
Set auth_time = CTE.at
    , auth_date = CTE.ad

From CTE
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

You can join to a subquery.
And in that subquery you're allowed to use group by.
Then do the casts or converts when the destination fields are set.

For example:

```
UPDATE b
SET 
 auth_time = left(replace(cast(h.max_run_time as varchar),':',''),8),
 auth_date = cast(h.max_run_date as datetime)
FROM inventory.dbo.books b
JOIN (
    select 
    job_id, 
    max(run_time) as max_run_time, 
    max(run_date) as max_run_date
    from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory 
    group by job_id
) h 
ON (b.job_id = h.job_id);
```

I didn't know what kind of number is expected in that auth_time.
So the max_run_time is just converted from a TIME to a VARCHAR.
The varchar is implicitly converted to the DECIMAL of the destination field.

For example: time '12:15:25.0000000' --> decimal(10,2) 121525.00